# How to get user access token using LinkedIn Javascript API like in Facebook?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am developing a native Mobile App and what i need is to pass a users's access token and get user details for doing mobile based operations. I was able to achieve the same in Facebook. But how can i get the access token of user via LinkedIn JavaScript API.

Facebook API way:

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
    console.log(response);    ===> GOT USER ACCESS TOKEN FROM THIS RESPONSE  
    testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }
```

Any help to get the same in LinkedIn will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [LinkedIn's Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens) on Exchanging JSAPI tokens for OAuth tokens.

Comment: Hi, the link you provided is broken.